# Adding "ENTER" after certain number of symbols in Word 2010 VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

So I have data in format  :

`data1|data2|data3|data4|data5|data6|...` etc.

I want Word to put <kbd>enter</kbd> (break line) after every 5th occurence of `|` in order to structure and separate data.

I cant find a simple and quick way to doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in `Split` function and rebuild the data string using the `vbCrLf` constant to add the line-feed.

Note that the `Split` function removes the delimiter, so if you need it in the output, you have to add it back when you add the strings in the `For` loop.

Something like the following could work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GroupDataStringByFive()
    Dim sIn As String
    Dim sOut As String
    Dim sArr() As String
    Dim iForCounter As Integer

    sIn = "data1|data2|data3|data4|data5|data6"

    sArr = Split(sIn, "|")

    If IsArray(sArr) Then
       For iForCounter = 0 To UBound(sArr)
           If iForCounter > 0 And iForCounter Mod 5 = 0 Then
               sOut = sOut & vbCrLf & sArr(iForCounter)
           Else
               sOut = sOut & sArr(iForCounter)
           End If
       Next iForCounter
    End If

    MsgBox sOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Had to tweak it to switch from MSgBox to something more useful but other then that - 100% perfect. I've very grateful for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome! I always think the MsgBox command is useful... ;)